# uncomment SSL configuration in server.xml, tomcat using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to write xslt file which would check the server.xml for SSL configuration.

- If SSL configuration is already there, leave it as it is.

  - Even if commented part is also there, it shouldn't be uncommented (otherwise two SSL configuration will be there) because SSL configuration is already available.
- If SSL configuration part is commented, uncomment the part.

  - if commented part is not there, we should put the SSL configuration ourselves.

I've wasted two days in finding a way to have a variable which will be set if there is no configuration found because we have multiple "Constructor" elements but couldn't succeed to set the variable. Please tell me how can I achieve what I need.

The server.xml is;

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="new2.xsl"?>
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->

    <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->

    <!--<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />-->

    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->

    **<!--<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />-->**



    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
           the request and response data received and sent by Tomcat.
           Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
      <!--
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
      -->

      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
           available for use by the Realm.  -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
        -->

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

and **Edited** xslt from the answer by JLRishe below is;

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()[not(../Connector[@scheme = 'https']) and
                                 contains(., 'Connector') and
                                 (contains(., 'scheme=https') or
                                  contains(., scheme='https'))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Service[not(Connector[@scheme = 'https'] or
                                   comment()[contains(., 'Connector') and
                                             (contains(., 'scheme=https') or
                                              contains(., scheme='https'))]
                                  )]">

    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

    <!-- Add the missing Connector here -->

    <xsl:element name="Connector">
      <xsl:attribute name="port">8443</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="protocol">HTTP/1.1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="SSLEnabled">true</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="maxThreads">150</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="scheme">https</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="secure">true</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="keystroreFile">${user.home}/.keystore</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="keystorePass">changeit</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="clientAuth">false</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="sslProtocol">TLS</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The above xslt just works for all scenarios except adding the new element when none is found, it is adding the Connector element just before `</Service>` closing tag but it is needed within `<Service>` before the `<Engine>` opening tag along with other Connector elements**

Thank you.

The produced xml when no SSL configuration found is following;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="new2.xsl"?>
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->

    <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->

    <!--<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />-->

    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->





    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
           the request and response data received and sent by Tomcat.
           Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
      <!--
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
      -->

      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
           available for use by the Realm.  -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
        -->

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keystroreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" /></Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for uncommenting the sought connector if there isn't already a matching one, or adding a new one if it's not there:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="Copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="insertConnector">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()[not(../Connector[@scheme = 'https']) and
                                 contains(., '&lt;Connector') and
                                 (contains(., 'scheme=&quot;https&quot;') or
                                  contains(., &quot;scheme='https'&quot;))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Service[not(Connector[@scheme = 'https'] or
                                   comment()[contains(., '&lt;Connector') and
                                             (contains(., 'scheme=&quot;https&quot;') or
                                              contains(., &quot;scheme='https'&quot;))]
                                  )]
                      ">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="insertConnector" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add the new connector after the last existing Connnector if there is one -->
  <xsl:template match="Connector[last()]" mode="insertConnector">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />

    <xsl:call-template name="AddConnector" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ... or before the first Engine if there is no existing Connector -->
  <xsl:template match="Engine[1][not(preceding-sibling::Connector)]"
                mode="insertConnector">
    <xsl:call-template name="AddConnector" />

    <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="AddConnector">
    <!-- This is the new connector -->
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" 
               keystroreFile="${{user.home}}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I wanted to remove the comments so using the 2nd option worked for me. 
But is there any way to deal with the following two scenarios?

1) where the commented SSL configuration is also available along with SSL configuration without comments? Above code will now make new xml with two SSL configurations (will remove the comments from commented SSL configuration)

2) There is no commented configuration so how will we find out that there is no configuration available? I know about adding a new SSL configuration when no commented configuration is available.

Thanks again

Comment: Please give the above a try. And please try to be more precise in your description. What you are asking to do is _uncomment_ some text, not remove comments.

Comment: I've edited the question now along with the scenarios which I need. Please guide me accordingly.

I really appreciate your answer and concern. Thank you.

Comment: I replied in the very first question about the code that 2nd option worked for me to uncomment the SSL part and I am really thankful to you for that but I still want to improve the code for the above mentioned scenarios. Do you want me to explain the scenarios? I explained in my first comment as well.

Comment: I think I understood your scenarios and I modified my answer. Have you tried the modified version yet?

Comment: Hi again, I'm sorry for asking but when I try to insert the missing Connector at your proposed place, it's generating error, "Error: Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added.". Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you modify your question text above to show that template with your portion added?

Comment: I edited my xslt in the question asked by me originally. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem was. The second template needed an `xsl:copy` surrounding its contents. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I actually tried it as well and it's generating Constructor element before the <Service> tag but I want it after the Service tag. Can you help with this?
I tried with it but couldn't succeed because I'm new to xslt.

Comment: The updates I made yesterday should place the `Constructor` element at the end of the inside of the `Service` element. Could you update your question to include your latest attempt.  Please note that the `<!-- Add the missing Connector here -->` is _inside_ the `<xsl:copy>` tags.

Comment: Hi, I added the produced xml in my question now. It's producing Connector element in place of </Service> tag but it's required within <Service> tag just before <Engine> tag.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize it needed to be inserted in a certain position within `Service`. I've now modified my answer to show how to insert the new `Connector` after the last already-existing `Connector`, or if there is no `Connector` already, before the first `Engine`. (BTW: your new comment in your question says that the connector is being added in place of the closing tag, but that's not true. The closing tag is there, just at the very end of the line.)

Comment: Hi, Are you sure about the call-template line in your solution i.e. <xsl:call-template name="Copy"> because it's generating error for ending tag and when I put ending tag </xsl:call-template> then it generates error that xsl:element can not be a child of xsl:call-template :S

we won't have a scenario where no connector is there because at least one connector should be there.

Comment: Sorry, there was a brief moment where I had an unterminated `xsl:call-template` right before I made another edit, and then that edit had a separate issue that I have now fixed and verified. Could you give the updated answer a try?

Comment: Great. It's perfect. You're a real xslt expert. Thank you :)
I'll have to work with it a little more about taking parameters of keystore file and keysotre password etc. will post a new question if I couldn't succeed in doing that but I'll try it to do it myself.

thanks again.
P.S. I corrected the question about "in place" of service tag.